# Sort NSmuatbleArray

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting

I need to sort array (in IOS) like this... 
let us suppose that i have an `NSMutableArray` with : 1,2,3,4,5
i need to build a new array with the last object in the middle and the middle will replace the last : 1.2.5.4.3... 
please help:
this is what i doing for now, i got only the 1.2.5 but i not success to put the 4.3 ...

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@1,@2,@3,@4,@5, nil];

int arrCount = (int)arr.count/2;
NSMutableArray *arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0;i < arr.count; i++) {
  if (i < arrCount) {
    [arr2 addObject:arr[i]];

  }
  else{
    index = i;
    [arr2 addObject:arr.lastObject];

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@1,@2,@3,@4,@5, nil];
NSMutableArray *arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arr];
int middleIndex = (int)arr.count/2;
id middleObject = arr2[middleIndex];
[arr2 replaceObjectAtIndex:middleIndex withObject:arr2.lastObject];
[arr2 replaceObjectAtIndex:arr2.count-1 withObject:middleObject];
NSLog(@"%@", arr2);
```